# Nginx setting timeout for dav_methods

Tags: nginx, timeout, bazel, nginx-config

I have an Nginx instance that I use as a Bazel cache with the config below. I'd like to set a low (4 second) timeout for the PUT (dav_methods) requests.

```
http {
  ...
  # request timed out
  client_body_timeout 2;
  client_header_timeout 2;

  # server will close connection
  keepalive_timeout 5;

  send_timeout 1;

  gzip on;

  server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    location ~ "<my regex>" {
      root <my dir>;
      dav_methods PUT;
      limit_except PUT GET { deny all; }
      create_full_put_path on;
    }
  }
}
```

With the config above. I don't ever see `GET` request response times more than 2 seconds, but `PUT` requests sometimes take 30-80s without timing out.

Am I missing a setting?

Comment: I wasn't able to find a fix; however, I did change the error log to debug mode and I was able to find/fix several problems.
`error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;`

Answer (score -1):

This might help you out https://www.nginx.com/blog/tuning-nginx/

Especially the **Limits** Section,

> You can set various limits that help prevent clients from consuming
>   too many resources, which can adversely the performance of your system
>   as well as security and the user experience.

Also those might help out in case you're using proxy

```
 fastcgi_read_timeout 3600s;
 proxy_connect_timeout       600;
 proxy_send_timeout          600;
 proxy_read_timeout          600;
 send_timeout                600;
```

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_read_timeout

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_connect_timeout

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_read_timeout

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#send_timeout

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In this case nginx is not used as a proxy and it doesn't use fastcgi.